# JQuery UI and DataTables

Tags: c#, jquery

over the past few weeks I've been putting together a c# application with heavy use of JQuery UI coupled with the DataTables.net table functionality. I have a quick question regarding session detection.

Now, i have detection in my Page_Load to check for session variables being present etc, but this doesn't prevent an end-user from clicking on tabs, and entering text client side.

So, my question is what is the best way to handle session variables, when using client side scripting like that of JQuery etc?

**EDIT**

What i'm trying to prevent from happening, is the end user trying to use the Filtering options of DataTables against a page that needs refreshing. For example, at the moment, my page just sits there with the processing dialog  - it's not until they either move to another page within the site, or hit the refresh Data button that they are redirected to the main login stage.

I guess, i'm looking for something, like checking for session login = true, when client side activity is performed.

Comment: What do you want to validate? it's really unclear.

Comment: Best practice would be to control what script is sent to the client via the server side.  You would never want to have those checks occur in javascript unless it is AJAX and the server is actually performing the check.  Essentially you do not want to leave your site open to any form of scripting attack that may be possible if you expose the access control functionality in the client script.

Answer (score 0):

You can define some public variable in your .cs file and use it in your .aspx file.like this :

Server Side :

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public bool sessionSet; // this is your variable
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Client Side :

```
<div
    <%if (!sessionSet)
      {
        %>
        style="display:none"
        <%  
      } %>
     >
     </div>
```

After checking session if the session not setted client will see this in page source:

```
 <div style="display:none"></div>
```